# make an iframe popup when image clicked in modal js only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a script that when someone clicks the image in the modal, an iframe pops up with a video. My current code follows:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");

for ( var e in img ) {
  img[e].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  }
}

var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

exit.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;  
}

.modal
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.85);
}

.modal-content
{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="kitchen">
    <img class="myImg" src="images/keuken.jpg" alt="keuken">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close"> &times</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to place an event listener on the image. This allows you to execute javascript when the image is clicked. Like so:

```
document.getElementById("img").addEventListener("click", openIframe);
```

The above calls the 'openIframe' function when the image is clicked.
Secondly, we need to add the iframe:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="https://your-url.com"></iframe>
```

you can hide it at first, so it won't be visible untill the image is clicked:

```
iframe#frame {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Then we'll define the function that will show your iframe:

```
function openIframe() {
    let iframe = document.getElementById("frame");
    iframe.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```